# Inherit an array that is initialised in the child

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I'm looking for the best way to do something like this:

```
class variable{
    protected:
    variable()
    int convert[][]
}

class weight: variable{
    public:
    weight(){
        convert = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,5}}
    }
```

Now I know I can't do this as I have to declare the array size in advance. I have many classes all inheriting from base class variable, and variable has a function using convert so don't want to declare convert in each one separately. For each class the array length will stay constant so using a list seems unnecessary.
What are your suggestions.

Many thanks.

Comment: So, what is the issue? It is not clear from your description. You need different array size in different derived classes or what?

Comment: I can't quite make out what your problem is, but it sounds like you're inheriting to reuse, not to extend so you might want to take one more look at your design to see if composition would serve you better.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options.

- Use `std::vector`.
- Or use `std::array` (available in C++11 only)
- Or do something like this:

  ```
  template<size_t M, size_t N>
  class variable{
     protected:
       int convert[M][N];
  };

  class weight: variable<3,2>{
  public:.
   weight(){
     //convert = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,5}} //you cannot do this for arrays
     //but you can do this:
     int temp[3][2] = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,5}};
     std::copy(&temp[0][0], &temp[0][0] + (3*2), &convert[0][0]);
  };
  ```
- Or you can use `std::vector` or `std::array` along with template as well.

Comment: Great thanks, so with the template option I'd have to assign each component individually, there isn't a way to delay the deceleration till the child class. Seems I might be best off using a vector or array after all.

Comment: @wookie1: Even with `std::vector`, you cannot populate it like that unless you can use C++11.

Comment: Neat, you've been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is better to use private pure virtual method in base class and implement it in derived classes. 
It is not clear does your "convert" array always have two dimensions that is why I use "your type" instead of real type that should be stored in returning container. Approximately it will look like this:

```
class variable {
private:
    virtual std::vector<"your type"> getConvertMatrix() const = 0;

    void someMethodThatNeedsConvertMatrix() {
        // ...
        std::vector<"your type"> convertMatrix = getConvertMatrix();
        // ...
    }
}

class weight : public variable {
private:

    virtual std::vector<"your type"> getConvertMatrix() const {
        // your implementation
        // form vector and return it, or return vector declared as member
    }
}
```